# Trigger a shell script on mail arrival

Tags: shell

How can I trigger a shell script on an email arrival that extracts the mail in a text file? I want to extract the information in the mail, process it to determine the request and send an automated response to that request. The mail will basically consist of a data request and the response will have the requested data in a text file attached to it.

Comment: It depends on your MTA (server side) or MUA (client side) so, consult your documentation.

Comment: What software are you using as mail server? Is that on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the documentation of your MTA (mail transfer agent). Many of them allow to run scripts or hooks when mail arrives and certain other conditions are met.

If you're using Linux and want a pure client solution (i.e. independent of the mail server software), then you should look at [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/). [The documentation](http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/) contains lots of useful tips and hints how to set up the tool ([like performance considerations](http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/#think_what_shell_commands_you_use)) and how to properly [set up the environment](http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/#things_to_remember) so your script executes correctly.

It also contains examples like a [service which responds to "ping" mails](http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/#service_ping_responder).